# Upload files using FS module

Tags: node.js

I get an error message when I use the FS module in NodeJS to upload some files with a simple HTML form.

It work in local, but it doesn't work on my remote server.

My NodeJS code :

```
exports.save = function(req, res){
    var title = req.body.title;
    var description = req.body.description;
    var screenshot = req.files.screenshot;
    var url = req.body.url;
    global.db.Project.create({
        title: title,
        screenshot: screenshot.name,
        description: description,
        url: url
    }).success( function(project){
        fs.rename(screenshot.path, './public/uploads/'+screenshot.name, function(err){
            if( err ) console.log(err);
        });
        res.redirect('/glovebox');
    })
}
```

My error message :

```
{ [Error: ENOENT, rename '/tmp/20282-8xsux1.png'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: '/tmp/20282-8xsux1.png' }
```

Anthony

Comment: Does `./public/uploads` exist on the server?

Comment: Yes, "./public/uploads" exists on my server and yes I can access to the "/tmp" directory too...

Comment: Is `screenshot.name` populated?

Comment: Yes because I'm able to see the data in my database and I see this one...

Comment: Your `public` folder lives within all you JavaScript sources and/or you do start the script from within the folder where `public` is located?

Comment: Whenever I had that issue, it was because I forgot the path is relative to where the script was executed, not relative to the script location.